# make the content of a button in keyboard empty - react-native

Tags: keyboard, react-native

I am using numeric keyboard in my program and I need to set one of the buttons on the keyboard empty - "." button should not exist, I just need numbers. How I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the native keyboard or making your own? You can't control which specific buttons show up. All you can do is handle the changes and decide to not keep non numbers.

Comment: No it is not my own, it is native keyboard, numeric one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a native keyboard, you cannot do this.

If you still want to do it, maybe you should create your own keyboard or look for a library with a customizable one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the native keyboard but disable the effect of non-numeric buttons, you could do something like this:

```
handleTextChange(text) {
  // remove non-numbers using regex
  text = text.replace(/\D/igm, '')
  this.setState({number: text})
}
...
<TextInput
  value={this.state.number}
  keyboardType="numeric"
  onChangeText={this.handleTextChange.bind(this)}
  ...
/>
```

Basically you're using the onChangeText call to catch the text change and then using the "not digit" regex selector `\D` you replace it with empty string.